# How to not synchronize all maps between services in Hazelcast

Tags: java, serialization, hazelcast

I have two different services (let's call them **Middleware** and **Gateway**) in my cluster setup to share the same cache. Middleware instances are sharing two Hazelcast maps *Session* and *Chat*. But in Gateway application I don't need Chat map, but only Session map. 
As far as I investigated thru Hazelcast documentation, there is no way to disable some map or type to be fully excluded from serialization\deserialization process.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Hazelcast maps are spread across all cluster members. So any process that has a part of the "*chat*" map also have a part of the "*session*" map.

The intention is for even data spread.
In a two-node cluster, if Node A had half of the "*chat*" map and all of the "*session*", and Node B only had the other half of the "*chat*" they would have different loading, so not give equal performance.

So directly you cannot do this.

There is a (commercial) security option that can restrict selected data from being accessed by some applications, so you could stop the Gateway application from accessing the "*chat*" map. The "*chat*" map would still be there, spread across the nodes.

If you really want one map to be one node and another map to be on two nodes, you need two separate clusters, each with one map.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Based on this information, I decided to remove Hazelcast from Gateway and replace it with REST calls to any instance of Middleware, since they all sharing the same cache. Having both maps Sessions and Chats on Gateway seemed too much of overhead